# Rails: Many to one ( 0 - n ) , finding records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've got tables `items` and `cards` where a card belongs to a `user` and a `item` may or may not have any cards for a given user.

The basic associations are set up as follows:

```
Class User
   has_many :cards

Class Item
   has_many :cards

Class Card
   belongs_to :user
   has_and_belongs_to_many :items
```

I've also created a join table, `items_cards` with the columns `item_id` and `card_id`. I'd like to make a query that tells me if there's a card for a given user/item. In pure SQL I can accomplish this pretty easily:

```
SELECT   count(id) 
FROM     cards 
JOIN     items_cards
ON       items_cards.card_id = cards.id
WHERE    cards.user_id = ?
AND      items_cards.item_id = ?
```

I'm looking for some guidance as to how I'd go about doing this via ActiveRecord. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an Item in `@item` and a User in `@user`, this will return 'true' if a card exists for that user and that item:

```
Card.joins(:items).where('cards.user_id = :user_id and items.id = :item_id', :user_id => @user, :item_id => @item).exists?
```

Here's what's going on:

`Card.` - You're making a query about the Card model.

`joins(:items)` - Rails knows how to put together joins for the association types it supports (usually - at least). You're telling it to do whatever joins are required to allow you to query the associated `items` as well. This will, in this case, result in `JOIN items_cards ON items_cards.card_id = cards.id JOIN items ON items_cards.item_id = items.id`.

`where('cards.user_id = :user_id and items.id = :item_id', :user_id => @user, :item_id => @item)` - Your conditional, pretty much the same as in pure SQL. Rails will interpolate the values you specify with a colon (`:user_id`) using the values in the hash (`:user_id => @user`). If you give an ActiveRecord object as the value, Rails will automatically use the id of that object. Here, you're saying you only want results where the card belongs to the user you specify, and there is a row for the item you want.

`.exists?` - Loading ActiveRecord objects is inefficient, so if you only want to know if something exists, Rails can save some time and use a `count` based query (much like your SQL version). There's also a `.count`, which you could use instead if you wanted to have the query return the number of results, rather than `true` or `false`.